# What are the chances of a fresh pilot school graduate to get a 'trainee' position at an airline in Europe?

Tags: flight-training, airline-pilot, career

My daughter (19) is about to start a career as a pilot. She completed the entry test to a pilot school in Norway (we live there) and got her Class 1 medical license. She's going to enroll for a 2-year training program, where - according to the school's training plan - she'll end up with ca. 230 logged hours (flight + sim combined) and an *EASA CPL(A) IR ME with frozen ATPL(A) plus MCC*.

Financing these two years is a significant investment, therefore I'd like to be sure that this really takes her somewhere with opportunities to continue. I looked around on some pilot career portals and career pages of major European airlines and I found that the qualifications listed above are roughly in line with the *minimum* requirements of entry programs at some airlines. My impression is that some job opportunities do exist for candidates with that level of (in)experience, but I'm not able to find any numbers e.g. for the number of positions open vs. the number of fresh pilots graduating from schools each year.

After completing that 2-year program, will my daughter stand in line as candidate nr. 1000 for a beginner's position at an airline? Or do airlines have such a high demand for new pilots that virtually anyone hitting the bare minimum can get in?

Comment: You should probably start by asking questions to the school offering the training program like "What percentage of your graduates are able to find a job as an airline pilot immediately upon graduation?"  Also, "What is the average starting pay for your graduates?"  Things like that will give you some practical insight into the "value" of their program.  If they don't have good answers, then the answers are probably not good.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there are also pilot schools directly from airlines, such as Lufthansa and Condor. But I don't know their pricing and their accessibility in Norway. Graduating from one of those would probably profit the opportunities after graduation.

Comment: There are many pilot forums online which are a better place to ask this kind of question.